# No output file with Jasmine and protractor

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

I'm a little frustrated. We're using Protractor for our automated testing framework, and a couple weeks ago I made the mistake of doing an npm update, which updated my jasmine module to version 2, and consequently broke all my tests. I've got the environment executing tests again, but jasmine doesn't create an XML file.  I read that protractor 1.6 is required to work with jasmine 2.*, but I can't seem to update protractor past version 1.5.  I've tried

```
npm update protractor
```

as well as

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/protractor.git
cd protractor
npm install
```

The second set of commands actually broke things again until I did an

```
webdriver-manager update
```

which brought me back to the original problem of being able to run tests, but not getting an xml file created with the results in it.

An example of one of my config files is:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['MyTest.js'],
    rootElement: 'div',
    allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
    onPrepare: function(){
        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        var junitReporter = jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            savePath: '/Automation/Results',
            consolidateAll: false
        });
    }
}
```

Which runs the test fine but no xml file is created in the Results folder. Is the problem that I just need to update Protractor to 1.6 to see the xml file?  If so, how do I do that on OSX?  If that's not the issue, does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Try to change path to  __dirname and check if file created in directory test runs.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Unfortunately I still didn't get the XML file created. I even searched the entire HDD to see if maybe it was getting created in a location I wasn't expecting, but no luck.  The file just doesn't get generated. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Combine with jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter); and __dirname. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to [add the reporter to the jasmine environment using `addReporter()`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters#basic-usage):

```
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    savePath: '/Automation/Results',
    consolidateAll: false
});
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it, but unfortunately I still don't seem to be getting the xml file in /Automation/Results. The test runs to completion, without any errors, but no XML file.  The onPrepare code is definitely being run, but it's as if the savePath is completely ignored.

Comment: @user2233949 okay, thanks, what if you change the path to `./Automation/Results` or `Automation/Results`?

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck.  I enumerated the properties of the junitReporter, and can see that the savePath property is being set correctly.  It just doesn't seem to actually put the file there.  Again, I appreciate the help.  When I saw your addReporter answer, I thought it was probably correct. It sounded very reasonable. I'll keep at it though.

Comment: @user2233949 thanks for trying it out. Can you also check the existence of the output directory and directory permissions? Thanks.

Comment: The directory does exist, and it seems to have the proper permissions. They are drwxr-xrwx. Also, I have the testcase take a screenshot that gets saved in the same folder, and that .png file gets created each time the test is run which would also indicate that permissions are fine. (I thought that may be the issue myself)  Thanks

Comment: @user2233949 good, still a wild guess, but what if you upgrade `jasmine-reporters` and/or `protractor` to the latest versions? Thanks.

Comment: I've actually been trying to update protractor and am not able to, which is making me think I've got deeper issues. On any other machine, I can run npm update -g protractor and end up on version 2. If I run the same command on this machine, I stay at version 1.5, although it seems to go through the update process.  Ugh.

Comment: One last comment. I realized that I have 2 protractor installations. One of them is getting updated to 2.0, but that is not the protractor in PATH.  I ran the test under the 2.0 version, but to my surprise, I got the exact same results. No XML file being created. I'll leave the question open in case anyone has any info to add, but I'm close to the point of calling it quits on this issue. It's unfortunate this all stems from running npm update. It's my fault, but I wouldn't expect that to cause so many issues.  Live and learn I guess.

Comment: @user2233949 thanks for coming back with it and sharing the fix!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it. Sort of anyway.  I had 2 installs of protractor. Once I figured that out, I needed to add

```
framework:'jasmine2'
```

to my exports.config in the Conf file. Once I did that and ran the test with Protractor 2.0, the xml file was created as expected. Apparently protractor defaults to the 1.x version of jasmine unless that framework property is set explicitly to jasmine2. I'm just not sure how I ended up with the 2 protractor installations, but everything seems to be working again.

Thanks to everyone for your help.